# How does the "copy image location" in right click menu of Firefox work?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am building an application where I need to add a new right click menu item that would fetch the image URL and post it somewhere. Is it possible to do both things with a single menu item?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to add context menus to the regular browser right click menu without installing an add-on to that browser.

An option would be to add a mouse click event to each image in question and check the event object that is returned.

```
var imageSrcInQuestion = "";
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i++){
    images[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
        if(event.which == 3){
            // this image has been right clicked on so capture it's data
            imageSrcInQuestion = this.src;
        }
    });
}
```

Then just set up a click event on your custom context menu button to post the imageSrcInQuestion variable to wherever it is needed.

If you haven't already got a custom context menu set up I would suggest adding a mousedown event to the document and then displaying a div with your context men items in the location of the event.clientX and event.clientY values.

Comment: HTML5 will let you alter the standard context menu: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-context-menu although it's currently only working in FF